# Strip BOM from a generated string (not a file)

Tags: powershell, byte-order-mark

I'm working with strings that look like they're MS Office documents. Note in this example, there are two BOM "characters," one at the start of the string and one in the body. Sometimes there are several of the characters, sometimes none. In the Powershell console, they print as ?

```
ï»¿<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=unicode"><meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 14 (filtered medium)"><style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
    <snip - bunch of style defs>
--></style></head><body lang=EN-US link=blue vlink=purple><div class=WordSection1>
<p class=MsoNormal style='text-autospace:none'>
 <span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'>ï»¿</span>
 <span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'>Testing <o:p></o:p></span>
</p></div></body></html>
```

The strings come from an object, so I can't simply force UTF8 encoding with Get-Content. How else might I strip them? I'm not worried about this being lossy, as this is just being piped to the display, thus the desire to strip the extra characters. I'll also be stripping the HTML.

Comment: Not that this snippet would tell you much, but to answer @Graimer question:
`$message = (Get-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration).ExternalMessage
Write-Host "The current message is $message"`

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this if there may be other actual UTF8 characters in the string would be to go this route.  It assumes the the byte order mark characters are at the beginning of each string though:

```
$bytes = @()
$strs | Foreach {$bytes += [byte[]][char[]]$_}

$memStream = new-object system.io.memorystream
$memStream.Write($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)
$memStream.Position = 0

$reader = new-object system.io.streamreader($memStream, [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
$reader.ReadToEnd()
$reader.Dispose()
```

Comment: I don't _expect_ to find other UTF8 characters, but I didn't expect to find these to start with! The problem is that I'm parsing just a single string with multiple lines, so this will be of limited help if it only catches the one st the start of the string.

Comment: In that case, use the -replace approach such Graimer suggests.  If there turns out to be other UTF8 chars, then use the script above after doing the replace.

Answer (score 1):

You should include the code you use to get your output when you ask for help. Does this work?

```
$s = #your code that gets the output#
$s -replace "ï»¿"  #returns output without the characters
```

Or

```
( code that creates output ) -replace "ï»¿"
```

Comment: Added the code in a comment to my question. Replace works for the rest of the string, but it doesn't seem to match ï»¿ (or any characters adjacent to that string. In fact, -match "ï»¿" returns False.

Comment: Hmm -match returns true in my experiments given the string you list in your question.  How did we get from replacing the UTF8 BOM sequence to doing a match?  What are you trying to do with -match?

Comment: I was just using -match to illustrate that the string wasn't being caught, my goal is still to drop the BOM. This is quite confusing. If I pipe this string out to a file and open in notepad++, it opens as UCS-2 Little Endian and the characters are not shown. If I force it to display as ANSI, they appear.

Comment: Are you saving the file at the end of the script? If so, you can try to run this AFTER it's saved `(Get-Content .\test.txt) -replace "ï»¿" | Set-Content .\test.txt` . I know it's a "dirty fix", but as a last resort it might work

Answer (score 1):

Here's a PowerShell script that I use to remove embedded UTF-8 BOM characters from my source files:

```
$files=get-childitem -Path . -Include @("*.h","*.cpp") -Recurse
foreach ($f in $files)
{
(Get-Content $f.PSPath) | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "\xEF\xBB\xBF", ""} | 
Set-Content $f.PSPath
}
```